# Is the projection onto the unit circle Sobolev?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Does $f \in W^{1,p}(B)$ for some $p \ge 1$, where $B$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

(I guess we can replace $B$ with a disk with arbitrarily small radius; the singularity is centered at the origin).

Here is what I know:

$f \le 1$ is bounded, so it is in $L^p(B)$ for any $p \ge 1$. Let us consider its derivatives:

$f_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2})\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, so for sure $f_x \in L^p(B)$ for $p<2$.

(In fact $f_x \in L^p(B) \iff p<2$).

$f_y=-\frac{yx}{x^2+y^2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$, so $|f_y|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, hence $f_y \in L^p(B)$ for $p<2$.

So, is it true that $f \in W^{1,p}(B)$ for some $ 1 \le p <2$?

Comment: I think that the answer to [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264792/8157) applies here and shows that these classical derivatives coincide with the distributional ones. Thus, $f\in W^{1,p}(B)$ for all $p\in[1, 2)$.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to me that you are right.

Comment: Great. I posted a small CW answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [the answer to this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264792/8157), since $f$ is singular at a point only its classical derivatives coincide with the distributional ones. Therefore, by definition, $f\in W^{1,p}(B)$ if and only if $f$ and $\nabla f$ belong to $L^p(B)$. The computations in the question show that this is the case for all $p\in[1, 2)$.

Comment: Thank you. By the way: Do you know if there is any "systematic way" to say something intelligent on the difference between the distributional derivative and the classical derivative, when they do *not* coincide? (let's say that I know that my function is smooth on an open set of full measure). My motivation comes from this question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328119/the-distributional-gradient-of-the-closest-isometry-to-the-differential-of-a-smo

Comment: Dear @AsafShachar, I have been thinking a bit at your question, but I am afraid I cannot say anything "intelligent". Of course, your function $q$ (cfr. MathOverflow question) is Sobolev if you assume that $U$ is not only full measure, but also that its complementary is codimension 2 or higher; this is the linked Fubini argument. With the only assumption that $U$ is full measure, the distributional derivative may differ from the classical one by a singular measure, supported in the complementary of $U$. As I said, this is not very intelligent, I am afraid.