# Is the normalized derivative of a holomorphic function Sobolev?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $B=\{z\in \mathbb C \,|\,|z|\le 1\}$ be the **closed** unit disk, and let $f:B \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic.

More precisely, I assume that $f$ is holomorphic **on the interior** $\text{int}(B)$, and smooth on the closed disk $B$.

> Assume also that $f'(z) \neq 0$ almost everywhere on $B$. Are the derivatives of $\frac{f'(z)}{\|f'(z)\|}$ in $L^1(B)$?

More precisely, if $f=u+iv$, then $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$, and I consider $$h(x,y)=\frac{u_x}{\sqrt{u_x^2+v_x^2}},g(x,y)=\frac{v_x}{\sqrt{u_x^2+v_x^2}}.$$

The question is whether or not $h_x,h_y,g_x,g_y \in L^1(B)$.

> I can show that for any $\epsilon >0$, the derivatives are integrable on $\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|\le 1-\epsilon\}$. The "remaining part" of the question is to determine what happens near the boundary.

I thought that if $f'(z) \neq 0$ a.e., then
$f'(z)$ may vanish only at finitely many points, [but this is not true in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74295/zeros-of-a-holomorphic-function-on-the-boundary-of-a-closed-region), since we have a non-empty boundary (where the usual identity theorem doesn't work). So, the case where $f'(z)$ has infinitely many zeros (with an accumulation point on the boundary) is still open.

**Here is a solution for the case where $f'$ has only finitely many zeroes:** (this implies that we are OK on every disk of radius $1-\epsilon$).

This problem reduces to analyzing what happens around a single zero, say at $z=0$. We can write $f'(z)=z^ng(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ satisfying $g(0) \neq 0$. Then $\frac{f'(z)}{\|f'(z)\|}=\frac{z^n}{\|z^n\|}\frac{g(z)}{\|g(z)\|}$. $g$ is smooth and non-zero in a neighbourhood of $z=0$, so the factor $\frac{g(z)}{\|g(z)\|}$ causes no problems. We are left with $\frac{z^n}{\|z^n\|}=(\frac{z}{\|z\|})^n=e^{in\theta}$, which reduces the problem to the analysis of the "argument function" $\theta$ (i.e. the case of $\frac{z}{\|z\|}$). A complete treatment of this can be found here in this [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192591/is-the-projection-onto-the-unit-circle-sobolev?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Near a point $a$ where $f'(a)=0$ you can write $f'(z)=(z-a)^ng(z)$, where $g(a)\neq0$. Then $f'(z)/|f'(z)|=\frac{(z-a)^n}{|z-a|^n}\frac{g(z)}{|g(z)|}$, which is a product of two bounded functions. By the way, $f'$ might vanish at infinitely many points, although finitely many in a compact.

Comment: Is $\mathbb D^2=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|\le 1\}?$ If so, that is strange notation in this context.

Comment: It seems to me the problem is on the boundary. At points in the open disc there is no problem.

Comment: 1) Yes, this is what I meant by $\mathbb D^2$. What notation do you suggest instead? 2) I agree with you that there is no problem at interior points, since they are isolated. The "remaining part" of the question is to determine what happens near the boundary.

Comment: It's just that very often $\mathbb D$ denotes the open unit disc in $\mathbb C.$  No need to change the notation, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I agree with zhw's suggestion on the notation. I was confused reading your question until the comments. "$\mathbb{D}^2$ be the closed two-dimensional unit disk" suggests a bidisc inside $\mathbb{C}^2$. It would be nice to say that the dimension is taken over the reals.  Generally when talking about holomorphic objects the complex dimension is more natural.

Comment: @AlanMuniz Thank you, I agree with you. I have changed the notation to be less confusing.